# Loopback SPI interface not working

Tags: pi-2, spi

I'm trying to do the loopback test for the SPI interface on my raspberrypi model 2 B V1.1,  by following the intruction on this website : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md

The output of this:

```
./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0
```

is:

```
spi mode: 0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)

00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00/dev/spidev0.0
```

I am able to locate the spidev0.0 : 
    /dev/spidev0.0

And I have properly connected the MISO to MOSI:

[image]

I really don't know why I'm not able to read anything. I have used the SPI interface lately and it was working well. Recently I have been seeing the thunderbolt symbol appearing on my PI, but I don't know if that would affect the SPI interface.

I also sometimes get a mmc0: hardware timeout error, and sometime it goes away, but again I don't know if that would affect the SPI interface.

Comment: Try the following commands. `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs spio 0 50000 0` then `pigs spix 0 10 11 12 13 14 15`  Is the returned value `6 10 11 12 13 14 15`?

Comment: No, the returned value is 6 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @joan Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: I changed my Pi and it worked. Very strange.

Comment: Perhaps the GPIO are bust on the first Pi.  See https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing